# Is there a way to simply count instances to show on an axis in d3 or dimple?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

My idea is to have a `addCategoryAxis("x", '"loc"');` such as `"Berlin, Deutschland"` and then to count the instances of jobs that are listed with that location, so, for instance I want to add something akin to a `chart.addMeasureAxis("y", '"title"';`, but I don't actually care what the value of `'"title"'` is, I just want to count the number of times something shows up there.

At the moment I'm using Dimple, and I've been reading through the API info, it says I can do something like this, spoiler alert- this doesn't work at all*:

```
// Add a Brand ordinal axis on "x"
 myChart.axes.push(new dimple.axis(myChart, "x", '"loc"', null));
// Add a Sales Volume linear numerical axis on "y"
 myChart.axes.push(new dimple.axis(myChart, "y", null, '"title"'));
// // Add a time axis on "x" for the date field
```

*With the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_hasCategories' of null`.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be achieved with either Dimple or D3?

This is just a toy dataset which is a simulacrum of my true data file, but it's useful as a self contained testing mechanism.

```
<div id="chartContainer">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</div>

<script>

console.log(data);

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 1000, 1000);
var data = [
          { '"loc"': '"Hamburg, Deutschland"', '"title"': "CNC-Dreher/in" },
          { '"loc"': 'M?nchen (Kreis), Bayern', '"title"': "Data Scientist" },
          { '"loc"': '"D?sseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen"', '"title"': "Praktikant m|w" },
          { '"loc"': '"Rheinland-Pfalz, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Senior Softwareentwickler Logistikdienstleistung(w/m)" },
          { '"loc"': '"D?sseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen"', '"title"': "Projektmanager (m/w) Information Engineering" },
          { '"loc"': '"Grimma, Leipzig (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Softwareentwickler (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Hannover, Region Hannover (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Bauleiter (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"M?nchen (Kreis), Bayern"', '"title"': "Backend Software Developer (m/f)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Ratingen, Mettmann (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Ausbildung Industriekaufmann (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Bayern, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Dualer Studiengang Bachelor of Arts (Fachrichtung Bank/Vertrieb) Bayern" },
          { '"loc"': '"Landshut, Landshut (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Spezialist CFK m/w" },
          { '"loc"': '"Frankfurt am Main, Hessen"', '"title"': "Data Analyst / Consultant analytisches CRM (m/w) f?r unseren Premium Partner EDEKA" },
          { '"loc"': '"Hamburg, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Produktmanager (m/w) im Bereich Privat Kraft" },
          { '"loc"': '"Unterf?hring, M?nchen (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Controller / Assistent der Gesch?ftsleitung" },
          { '"loc"': '"Berlin, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Projektmanager (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': 'Royal Leamington Spa', '"title"': "SOFTWARE TEST ENGINEER / QA (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Lauf an der Pegnitz, N?rnberger Land (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Bilanzbuchhalter/in" },
          { '"loc"': '"Buchenb?hl, N?rnberg"', '"title"': "Inhouse Business Intelligence Berater (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Berlin, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Praktikant Vertriebscontrolling (m/w) f?r die Dauer von 6 Monaten (Pflichtpraktikum)" }
        ];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
chart.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 300);

// Add a Brand ordinal axis on "x"
var x =  chart.axes.push(new dimple.axis(chart, "x", '"loc"', null));
// Add a Sales Volume linear numerical axis on "y"
var y =  chart.axes.push(new dimple.axis(chart, "y", null, '"title"'));
// // Add a time axis on "x" for the date field

var lines = chart.addSeries(["project"], dimple.bar, [x, y]);

lines.data = data;
lines.lineWeight = 5;
lines.lineMarkers = true;

chart.draw();

</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So in the question I had :

```
var x =  chart.axes.push(new dimple.axis(chart, "x", '"loc"', null));

var y =  chart.axes.push(new dimple.axis(chart, "y", null, '"title"'));
```

I changed this to :

```
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", '"loc"');

var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", '"title"');
```

And it worked. Updated code :

```
<div id="chartContainer">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</div>

<script>

console.log(data);

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 1000, 1000);
var data = [
          { '"loc"': '"Hamburg, Deutschland"', '"title"': "CNC-Dreher/in" },
          { '"loc"': 'M?nchen (Kreis), Bayern', '"title"': "Data Scientist" },
          { '"loc"': '"D?sseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen"', '"title"': "Praktikant m|w" },
          { '"loc"': '"Rheinland-Pfalz, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Senior Softwareentwickler Logistikdienstleistung(w/m)" },
          { '"loc"': '"D?sseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen"', '"title"': "Projektmanager (m/w) Information Engineering" },
          { '"loc"': '"Grimma, Leipzig (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Softwareentwickler (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Hannover, Region Hannover (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Bauleiter (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"M?nchen (Kreis), Bayern"', '"title"': "Backend Software Developer (m/f)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Ratingen, Mettmann (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Ausbildung Industriekaufmann (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Bayern, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Dualer Studiengang Bachelor of Arts (Fachrichtung Bank/Vertrieb) Bayern" },
          { '"loc"': '"Landshut, Landshut (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Spezialist CFK m/w" },
          { '"loc"': '"Frankfurt am Main, Hessen"', '"title"': "Data Analyst / Consultant analytisches CRM (m/w) f?r unseren Premium Partner EDEKA" },
          { '"loc"': '"Hamburg, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Produktmanager (m/w) im Bereich Privat Kraft" },
          { '"loc"': '"Unterf?hring, M?nchen (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Controller / Assistent der Gesch?ftsleitung" },
          { '"loc"': '"Berlin, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Projektmanager (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': 'Royal Leamington Spa', '"title"': "SOFTWARE TEST ENGINEER / QA (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Lauf an der Pegnitz, N?rnberger Land (Kreis)"', '"title"': "Bilanzbuchhalter/in" },
          { '"loc"': '"Buchenb?hl, N?rnberg"', '"title"': "Inhouse Business Intelligence Berater (m/w)" },
          { '"loc"': '"Berlin, Deutschland"', '"title"': "Praktikant Vertriebscontrolling (m/w) f?r die Dauer von 6 Monaten (Pflichtpraktikum)" }
        ];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
chart.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 300);

// // Add a Brand ordinal axis on "x"
// var x =  chart.axes.push(new dimple.axis(chart, "x", '"loc"', null));
// // Add a Sales Volume linear numerical axis on "y"
// var y =  chart.axes.push(new dimple.axis(chart, "y", null, '"title"'));
// // // Add a time axis on "x" for the date field

// chart.addCategoryAxis("x", '"loc"');
// chart.addMeasureAxis("y", '"title"');

var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", '"loc"');
var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", '"title"');

var lines = chart.addSeries(["project"], dimple.bar, [x, y]);

lines.data = data;
lines.lineWeight = 5;
lines.lineMarkers = true;

chart.draw();

</script>
```

Comment: Explain what you did. I understand what you did, but an explanation may help others

Comment: hmm, :/ for sure I'll do it next time, but I've been looking at it and I can't remember what I did

Comment: var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", '"loc"');
var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", '"title"');

Comment: yeah but how is that different than what I posted in the question?

Comment: ok so- yeah- much better than the one I put- next time I'll make it nice.

Comment: what do you think about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947135/automatically-set-dimensions-of-d3-dimple-data-visualization-for-legibility)?